chaining implications and equivalences in proofs
I have a question (more of a "sanity check") regarding the interpretation of proofs one often encounters, particularly in university-level courses where proofs are written on blackboards.
Let me illustrate my concern with two examples:
Example 1
If, for three sets $A, B, C$, we have
$$ A \cup B \subset C, $$
then it follows that
$$ A \cap B \subset C. $$
Proof:
$$
A \cup B \subset C \Rightarrow A \subset C \Rightarrow A \cap B \subset C.
$$
Example 2
For any two sets $A, B$, we have the identity
$$
(A \cup B)' = A' \cap B',
$$
where $A' = X \setminus A$ and $B' = X \setminus B$.
Proof:
Let $x \in X$.
$$
x \in (A \cup B)' \iff x \notin A \cup B \iff (x \notin A) \wedge (x \notin B) \iff x \in A' \wedge x \in B' \iff x \in A' \cap B'.
$$
My Question
My understanding is that, although the first proof is structured as a chain of implications, written as
$$ p \Rightarrow q \Rightarrow r, $$
what is really meant here is
$$
\{p \text{ and } [(p \Rightarrow q) \wedge (q \Rightarrow r)]\} \Rightarrow r.
$$
The proof is structured in this compact way to avoid repeating certain formulas multiple times. For instance, if written out in full detail, the statement $q$ would appear twice.
In the second example, we similarly do not mean
$$ p \iff q \iff r \iff s \iff t, $$
but rather
$$
(p \iff q) \wedge (q \iff r) \wedge (r \iff s) \wedge (s \iff t).
$$
Only the second formulation implies $p \iff t$, while the first one could also hold in cases like $p = \text{true}$ and $q = r = s = t = \text{false}$.
Specific Question
Is my reasoning correct? Do you find "chained implications" or "chained equivalences" problematic, especially from a teaching perspective?

This is a math question, not a math education question. I suggest posting it at math SE.

@SueVanHattum: sorry, I redirected it from MathOverflow to here. It certainly isn't research level and "from a teaching perspective" caught my eye. But math SE could be more appropriate.  (To the asker of the question, yes we have three mathematics sites on StackExchange.)

@SueVanHattum: I tend to disagree. In my experience, this is indeed particularly relevant in teaching, where some (many?) people use implication arrows as short hand notation to indicate the logical structure of an argument. The question whether this is problematic from a pedagogical perspective also seems very relevant for this site.

@SueVanHattum   I have previously asked at SE, and was asked to move it here, as it is apparently not a math question, but math education question.

I meant at " math SE"

Ahh, I missed "especially from a teaching perspective". Very good.

I’m voting to close this question because This question is off-topic because it is a mathematical question as contrasted with a question about mathematics education. For a Stack Exchange site for mathematical questions please see Mathematics.

@AndrásBátkai: It's not a mathematical question. It's a question of notation especially when teaching students. Answering it requires not only knowing the underlying logic of chained relations, but also knowing how to teach it, as well as precedence rules and other syntactic issues.

@AndrásBátkai   "For a Stack Exchange site for mathematical questions please see Mathematics." I was asked to remove that question from there, as this was not a mathematical question.

There is nothing wrong with using chained relations in general, such as "A ∈ B ⊆ C", which means "A ∈ B and B ⊆ C". The issue here is that we ought to explicitly teach chained relations and exactly what they mean. In particular, if you wish to use chained implications or equivalences, you ought to emphasize that in itself the chain "A ⇒ B ⇒ C" asserts just the conjunction of the implications and does not actually assert "A" or other things. The fact that you can deduce "A ⇒ C" from this chain is something that you have to explain.
Don't think that this is an insignificant matter. Many teachers use chained inequalities without ever teaching them properly. For example, if you write "$x^2-4x+7 = (x-2)^2 + 3 ≥ 3 > 1$", you need to use the facts about chained inequalities to deduce "$x^2-4x+7 > 1$". Just because no expert writes down those extra deductive steps, does not imply that you don't have to teach the students, because most of them would not obtain 100% understanding on their own.
Additionally, I personally disagree with using implication chains, because I strongly prefer to use "⇒" to denote the conditional boolean operation, in which case we cannot reuse the same symbol as a relation-symbol! And we never need an implication chain anyway. Here is a full proof of your problem (in a Fitch-style system extending this one):
Given any sets A,B,C:
  If A⋃B ⊆ C:
    Given x∈A⋂B:
      x∈A.
      x∈A⋃B.
      x∈C.
    Therefore A⋂B ⊆ C.
I would say that students who cannot produce the above proof should not be allowed to use your proof either, and besides your proof is not clear at all. It is better to use chained subset relations as follows:
Given any sets A,B,C:
  If A⋃B ⊆ C:
    A⋂B ⊆ A ⊆ A⋃B ⊆ C.
For chained equivalences, I would also not use "⇔", as I reserve that as the boolean operation, but instead I would use "≡" as follows:
Given any sets A,B,V:
  Given any x∈V:
    x∈V∖(A⋃B)
    ≡ x∈V ∧ X∉A⋃B
    ≡ X∉A⋃B
    ≡ ¬( X∈A ∨ X∈B )
    ≡ X∉A ∧ X∉B
    ≡ ( X∈V ∧ X∉A ) ∧ ( X∈V ∧ X∉B )
    ≡ X∈V∖A ∧ X∈V∖B
    ≡ X∈(V∖A)⋂(V∖B).
  Therefore V∖(A⋃B) = (V∖A)⋂(V∖B).
